# Some JavaScript files do not start correctly with node/nodemon in src/

Tags: node.js, npm, nodemon, npm-scripts

Well, the problem is simple to explain and although I have investigated I have not found a solution

When I start the project in **src/** with either `nodemon src/ --ignore src/public/*`(with the `npm start` script) or `node src/` commands only two *.js* files are executed in **src/** and these are web3.js and index.js, **nodemon and node completely ignore the existence of database.js**

I thought that the error might be in the code in database.js so I created the file test.js which makes a simple console.log to check if it was executed but not

The files are structured as follows:

```
src/
 -  database.js
 -  index.js
 -  test.js
 -  web3.js
package.json
config.toml
```

I tried to run the database.js file independently with node and got this error, which is weird because in web3.js and index.js I also get the toml file the same way.

```js
> node src/database.js
node:internal/fs/utils:345
    throw err;
    ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './config.toml'
```

The code that gives this error, although irrelevant, here it is

```js
const { readFileSync } = require("fs");
const { mongoUriOp } = toml.parse(readFileSync("./config.toml", 'utf-8'));
```

I tried (thanks to a comment) changing the config path to `"../config.toml"` and the file ran with `node database`, but it still won't run with `npm start` or `node src/`.

Comment: What happens if you try `readFileSync("../config.toml", 'utf-8')`. It looks like the `config.toml` file is in the directory outside of `database.js`

Comment: @John It is strange, since in web3.js and index.js I have `"./config.toml"` and it has not given me any problem, although with `"../config.toml"` now the file runs fine starting it individually with `node database` but still does not start with `npm start` or `node src/`

Comment: Do you import or reference `databas.js` inside `index.js`?

Comment: Maybe this answer is helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/a/50559862/1471485

Comment: Try to add the `watch` flag. `nodemon --watch src --ignore src/public/*`. Docs: https://github.com/remy/nodemon#monitoring-multiple-directories

Comment: @John You gave me the idea to try requiring the file in index and it already runs correctly, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:
From the comments, it looks like you figured it out by importing (require) all your files in `index.js`. I have a feeling that your package.json file has a field `main`, and it is set to `src/index.js`.

It's difficult to understand what you are having trouble with.
I'm assuming you want to watch for changes in all of your JavaScript files inside the `src` folder.

You could try to add the `watch` flag to your command
inside package.json.

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "nodemon --watch src --ignore src/public/*"
}
```

[Link to doc for reference](https://github.com/remy/nodemon#monitoring-multiple-directories)